# React Basics - Passing Props to Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React so please forgive me if this is very basic stuff.

I have a component that renders the following (there could be 100s of this on a page)

```
<a onClick={this.handlePropChange} propRef={this.props.proposal.PROPREF} >View</a>
```

When i click the button i want to load a modal and pass through the value of propRef to a modal component (so i can then use some API calls to access information relating to that proposal).

```
handlePropChange(event) {
    alert(event.target.propRef);
    $('#proposalModal').modal('show');
}
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? Like i said i know this is basic but i'm struggling today.

Comment: I suggest you to check the official documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use jQuery with React which is an anti-pattern (they have different processes for updating the DOM and they will clash). Ideally you should use [a portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) for your modal, and store variables in a state which the modal can have access to.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions :

- Using a data attribute

```
<a onClick={this.handlePropChange} data-prop-ref={this.props.proposal.PROPREF}>
  View
</a>

handlePropChange(event) {
  alert(event.target.dataset.propRef);
  ...
}
```

- Passing propRef as a parameter of `handlePropChange` function

```
<a onClick={() => this.handlePropChange(this.props.proposal.PROPREF)}>
  View
</a>

handlePropChange(propRef) {
  alert(propRef);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the jQuery issue.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with jQuery. He is just asking how to retrieve an attribute from a callback (probably needed to call an API)

Comment: What do you think `$('#proposalModal').modal('show');` is?